# Android new/edit AVD dialog missing "Hardware:" field options

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm running Eclipse Juno 4.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit, with all Android SDK versions installed, android plug-in for Eclipse up to date also.

I've been reading some android tutorials online and I see that the AVD Manager (the **Edit AVD screen** only) looks a bit different comparing with my version:

On mine are missing the Hardware settings at the bottom of the screen.
In addition I don't have the options to change the screen resolution also.

Does anybody experience the same? Is it because of the OS (in my case Ubuntu), or the new version of ADT doesn't have these settings any more, or is it just a bug?

I would like to post images but for some reason the editor doesn't let me do it, it keeps displaying an error that I need at least 10 reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it because of the OS (in my case Ubuntu), or the new version of ADT doesn't have these settings any more, or is it just a bug?

AVDs created using the newer version of the AVD Manager use the Device Definition tab for the things you seek. There you can create new devices, and when you create an AVD, you choose the device you want from the Device drop-down.

> I would like to post images but for some reason the editor doesn't let me do it, it keeps displaying an error that I need at least 10 reputation.

That is because you are new to StackOverflow. Feel free to upload images elsewhere on the Web and link to them from your questions.

Comment: Now I see, thanks a lot, definitely I'll subscribe for your book